# django form dynamic select box

Tags: python, django

I don't understand what's happening, I have in my form
`mylist = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.SelectMultiple, label='MyList',help_text = "help")`
I then have some jquery on the page that adds dynamic values to this, but when I submit the form I get form.is_valid to false "object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'"

This seems to only happens when after i dynamically add values to the select box if I select some before submitting. If I don't select values the cleaned_data["mylist"] is empty array.

How do I fix this? Basically I want to access my dynamically added list of values from django form after submission.

```
edit
-----
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        action = request.POST['submit']

        if action == 'Update':
                mylist = form.cleaned_data['mylist']
    else:
        form = MyForm()
```

### edit

```
def clean_mylist(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data('mylist')
    return data


def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: Can you post how you are processing the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit the form `MultipleChoiseField` validates that all selected items belong to choises parameter of the `MultipleChoiseField`. If you dynamically later add fields they are naturally not in the choises set. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield).

As solution you could think of using `CharField` with `SelectMultiple` widget and override the clean-method.

Comment: I tried to override the clean class and return the value but i'm still getting the validation error